# Can I make Docker do always a pull when performing a run?

Tags: docker

We regularly push new versions of our containers to our private Docker registry. We also have a set of containers we start when we need them like so:

```
docker run -e "env=val" -p 9001:80 --name blah --rm our_repo/the_image:latest
```

The thing we run into is when we push a new version of `the_image:latest` to our registry, our machines will already have a `the_image:latest` cached locally and it seems that the `run` command does not perform a `pull` of the image.

Is there a way to make it do that other than always having to manually issue a `docker pull our_repo/the_image:latest` command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
docker run --pull=always
```

is merged here [github](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1498)

> will ship as part of `Docker 19.09` but you can download nightly
>   builds with that change

[commit](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13331#issuecomment-493531462)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Linpy you can try the nightly builds, but if you do not want to update you can try the below command. It will pull the image on every run.

```
docker run -it $(docker pull alpine | grep Status |  awk 'NF>1{print $NF}')
```

Or

```
docker run -e "env=val" -p 9001:80 --name blah --rm $(docker pull our_repo/the_image:latest | grep Status |  awk 'NF>1{print $NF}')
```

You can also use `AWK` with out grep

```
docker run -it $(docker pull alpine |  awk 'END{print}' | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}')
```

Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
image_name="${1}"
docker run -it $(docker pull $image_name |  awk 'END{print}' | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}')

$ ./test.sh alpine
```